# Asserting timestamp with microseconds equals mysql database value in Ecto/Phoenix

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've been playing around with Elixir Phoenix and have a simple integration test that checks that a json response of a model is the same as the json-rendered representation of that model.

The test looks like this:

```
test "#show renders a single link" do
    conn = get_authenticated_conn()
    link = insert(:link)

    conn = get conn, link_path(conn, :show, link)

    assert json_response(conn, 200) == render_json(LinkView, "show.json", link: link)
end
```

This used to work fine but following a recent `mix deps.update` the test has broken due a precision problem with the timestamps of the model. Here is the output from the test:

```
Assertion with == failed
     code: json_response(conn, 200) == render_json(LinkView, "show.json", link: link)
     lhs:  %{"id" => 10, "title" => "A handy site to find stuff on the internet", "url" => "http://google.com", "inserted_at" => "2017-01-09T19:27:57.000000", "updated_at" => "2017-01-09T19:27:57.000000"}
     rhs:  %{"id" => 10, "title" => "A handy site to find stuff on the internet", "url" => "http://google.com", "inserted_at" => "2017-01-09T19:27:56.606085", "updated_at" => "2017-01-09T19:27:56.606093"}
```

We can see that the timestamps of the response given by the controller compared to the json rendering of the model do not match. This is because the MySQL database (5.7) rounds microseconds down to 0 whilst the in-memory Ecto model representation supports higher accuracy. My migration just uses Ecto's `timestamps` function.

What's the best way to get these tests to pass? I don't particularly care about microsecond precision for my timestamps but clearly Ecto has made it more accurate in a recent update. I have a feeling it might be a problem with MariaEx but not sure how to solve.

Comment: Try adding `@timestamps_opts [usec: false]` just above the `schema "..." do` call in the relevant model(s). That should make Ecto behave like before and not use microsecond precision.

Comment: That does the trick! Many thanks, post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Ecto v2.1 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/v2.1/CHANGELOG.md#integration-with-elixir-13-calendar-types), to get the old behavior of not keeping `usec`  in automatic timestamps (like it was until Ecto < v2.1), you can add the following module attribute just before the call to `schema` in the relevant model(s):

```
@timestamps_opts [usec: false]
```

Comment: Is there some way to solve this only in the test configuration?

Comment: @jay Can you try this and see if it works: `@timestamps_opts [usec: Mix.env != :test]`?

Comment: Yeah that works! I wonder if there would be some way to achieve the same but in the test_helper.. I'm new to elixir and Phoenix so I'm not sure yet

Comment: I don't think this can be applied to all models from test_helper, but you could write your own assertion function that removes `usec` before comparing and use that in your tests.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack - essentially these datetime objects are maps.. so this will most likely start with seconds now.. so ...12:33:33 is > 11:22:34 .. which is clearly wrong. 

Comparing complex types like this won't work - honestly, I think I just hit a massive pain point here with Ecto/Elixir.. pretty rough when you're trying to figure out why a "simple" DateTime comparison in a where clause is so difficult. haha